# extend functionality of Zend_Form_Element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-framework3

I'm still wondering when and where I have to register new classes and how to extend old ones.
For example I found a nice code which extends Zend_Form_Element_Select so that I can use it in each form and pass my database specifications to.

Because I thought, it would be a good idea to have an own directory I added a folder src\Service at modulelevel.

First question: Is that clever to have it at modulelevel? Would it be more convenient to have it at rootlevel so that I could use it in several modules? Do I have to register it?

The class extends `Zend_Form_Element_Select` which I added with a use statement:

```
use Zend\Form\Element\Select;
```

This causes a fatal error :

> Fatal error: Class 'Import\Service\Zend_Form_Element_Select' not found

This would be my next question: How can I add this Zend_Form_Element properly. I think the problem might be that Zend doesn't look in the Zend-Directory. But I used the `Zend_Form_Element_Select` in other forms so it is there. But my new class doesn't know it. How would I do it, if I want to use own classes which of course use Zend-Classes?

I'm searching basically for a way how to do it in general. The target would be to easy reuse classes in other projects.

EDIT1: additional code snippets

here is the class I found online:

```
Module\Import\src\Service\CU_Form_Element_DbSelect

<?php

namespace Import\Service;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element\Select;
use Zend\Form\Element;

class CU_Form_Element_DbSelect extends Zend_Form_Element_Select {

    private $_dbAdapter;
    private $_dbSelect;

    private $_identityColumn = 'id';
    private $_valueColumn = '';

    /**
     * Set the database adapter used
     * @param Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $adapter
     */
    public function setDbAdapter(Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $adapter) {
        $this->_dbAdapter = $adapter;
    }

    /**
     * Set the query used to fetch the data
     * @param string|Zend_Db_Select $select
     */
    public function setDbSelect($select) {
        $this->_dbSelect = $select;
    }

    /**
     * Set the column where the identifiers for the options are fetched
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setIdentityColumn($name) {
        $this->_identityColumn = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the column where the visible values in the options are fetched
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setValueColumn($name) {
        $this->_valueColumn = $name;
    }

    public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null) {
        $this->_performSelect();
        return parent::render($view);
    }


    private function _performSelect() {
        if(!$this->_dbAdapter)
            $this->_dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

            $stmt = $this->_dbAdapter->query($this->_dbSelect);
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $options = array();

            foreach($results as $r) {
                if(!isset($r[$this->_identityColumn])) {
                    throw new Zend_Form_Element_Exception(
                            'Identity column is not present in the result');
                }

                if(!isset($r[$this->_valueColumn])) {
                    throw new Zend_Form_Element_Exception(
                            'Value column is not present in the result');
                }

                $options[$r[$this->_identityColumn]] = $r[$this->_valueColumn];
            }

            $this->setMultiOptions($options);
    }
}
```

Here also a snippet of my first form in which I wanted to use it in:

```
namespace Import\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Import\Service\CU_Form_Element_DbSelect;
.....

$this->add(new CU_Form_Element_DbSelect(array(
                'name' => 'ProjectID',
                'dbAdapter' => $this->db,
                'dbSelect' => 'SELECT ProjectID, Projectname FROM t_project',
                'valueColumn' => 'ProjectID',
                'label' => 'Choose project'
        )));
```

For me the error message looks like `extends Zend_Form_Element_Select`  is not found.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to have your own class on module level. You also can use it on another module. Just call the class using `use`. As long as the module registered in `config/modules.config.php` you can use it in another modules.

Where is to put the `class`? Depend on your need. You can put it in root of module

```
ExampleModule/src/YourClass.php
```

or you can put it on `Service` folder. I usually put my own class on this folder if this class can be used as service

```
ExampleModule/src/Service/Yourclass.php
```

And about this error, please add `namespace Import\Service` to your `Zend_Form_Element_Select` class.

> Fatal error: Class 'Import\Service\Zend_Form_Element_Select' not found

I see this caused by `Autoloader` cannot find it because it don't use the correct `namespace`. Please use the correct namespace, related the module name and path (eg:  `Import\Service`).

To make your class reusable in another project, you can follow how `Zend Modules` created. They can be install and uninstall using composer. The first, you need to know how composer work.

Comment: of course I have the namespace added, anyway I think it would be best to post the code, then you can see whats already done. composer is no topic in here.

Comment: I have check your code. And I think there will be much problem. `Zend_View_Interface`, `Zend_Db_Table`, `Zend_Db` and `Zend_Form_Element_Exception` will also not found. You need to load them too. And I assume there will be much dependecies more from those `class`. There is `zendframework/zendframework1` package in `packagist`. It contain all libraries from **ZF1**. You can try adding this to your composer `"zendframework/zendframework1": "^1.12"`, but I'm not sure it will be working well in your project.

Comment: ok I understand, so how could I build something like this in ZF3?

Comment: You need to convert it to using Zend Modules like `Zend\Db\Adapter`, `Zend\Db\TableGateway`, `Zend\Form\Element`, `Zend\View`, etc. This caused by there are much different between ZF1 and ZF2. For ZF2 and ZF3 there is no much different

Comment: that's all? Ok, I will try this. I'm sometimes a bit confused I use several prgramming languages and ZEND1 and Zend3 and sometimes I'm kind of lost in Syntax ;-)